# In my actions, when should I use @variable_name, only when I need it in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do I only prefix var names with @ if I need that variable in a view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you want to use @variable_name (instance variables) when you want to access these variables outside of the local scope, one example is using them in the view.

Another example:

```
before_filter :setup

def index
# can access @profile
end

private

def setup
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
end
```